# Android Draw the customized Shape using Stroke in Canvas

Tags: android

Using stroke in canvas how to draw the given below Image.

I can Draw straight Line how to Blend stroke

MY Code Here

```
   Paint  mBarBorderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
   mBarBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

     @Override
   public void drawData(Canvas c) {
       drawDataSet(c, set, i);
     }
```

[image: Customized shape of an Image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. A Line maintains its thickness for all its length. You have to create small lines (at different rotation) with small thickness changes so from the human eye that line has a progressive thickness changes.

Comment: Can u Join That two Line

Comment: You have to create intermediate "fake" small-lines that has the relative intermediate thickness from starting to ending thickness. Example: you need a thickness from 1 to 4, tjen you have to create a small connection line of 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 of thickness in the connection point and at right orientation each of them.

Comment: You just have to put a "fake"/additional intermediate points (with progressive thickened changes) between the two lines you're already drawing.